# How exactly does 'order' parameter in imgaug.augmenters.Affine work?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, image-manipulation

I've been using imgaug to augment data for my project. Naturally, I'd use affine transformations, so I understand that we use the `order` parameter to choose the interpolation method. The way to choose interpolation looks quite obscure, though, at least to me.

Let's say this is my augmenter (it's a part of `Sequential()` augmenter):

```
iaa.Affine(scale             = {"x": (+0.8, +1.0), "y": (+0.8, +1.0)},
                translate_percent = {"x": (-0.2, +0.2), "y": (-0.2, +0.2)},
                rotate            = (-5, +5),
                shear             = ( -5,  +5),
                order             = [1, 2], #interpolation
                cval              = 255, 
)
```

As far as I know, `order = [1,2]` stands for bi-quadratic interpolation, and `order = [0,1]` stands for linear interpolation. What does it mean? How do I get other interpolations, such as bicubic or Lanczos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Use the Source, Luke". Either [directly](https://github.com/aleju/imgaug/blob/master/imgaug/augmenters/geometric.py), or from docstring with `help` function.

```
order : int or iterable of int or ia.ALL or StochasticParameter, optional(default=1)
Interpolation order to use. Same meaning as in
skimage:
        * 0: Nearest-neighbor
        * 1: Bi-linear (default)
        * 2: Bi-quadratic (not recommended by skimage)
        * 3: Bi-cubic
        * 4: Bi-quartic
        * 5: Bi-quintic
Method 0 and 1 are fast, 3 is a bit slower, 4 and 5 are very
slow.
        * If a single int, then that order will be used for all images.
        * If an iterable, then for each image a random value will be sampled
          from that iterable (i.e. list of allowed order values).
        * If ia.ALL, then equivalant to list [0, 1, 3, 4, 5].
        * If StochasticParameter, then that parameter is queried per image
          to sample the order value to use.
```